# Errors when trying to call pycurl in a lambda on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, layer, pycurl

I want to use pycurl in order to have TTFB and TTLB, but am unable to call pycurl in an AWS lambda.

To focus on the issue, let say I call this simple lambda function:

```
import json
import pycurl
import certifi


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client_curl = pycurl.Curl()
    client_curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
    client_curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "https://www.arolla.fr/blog/author/edouard-gomez-vaez/")              #set url
    client_curl.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    client_curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, lambda x: None)
    content = client_curl.perform()
    dns_time = client_curl.getinfo(pycurl.NAMELOOKUP_TIME) #DNS time
    conn_time = client_curl.getinfo(pycurl.CONNECT_TIME)   #TCP/IP 3-way handshaking time
    starttransfer_time = client_curl.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)  #time-to-first-byte time
    total_time = client_curl.getinfo(pycurl.TOTAL_TIME)  #last requst time
    client_curl.close()

    data = json.dumps({'dns_time':dns_time,
                       'conn_time':conn_time,
                       'starttransfer_time':starttransfer_time,
                       'total_time':total_time,
    })

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': data
    }
```

I have the following error, which is understandable:

```
    Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pycurl'
```

I followed the tuto https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/ in order to create a layer, but then have the following error while generated the layer with docker (I extracted the interesting part):

```
    Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config': 'curl-config'
```

I even tried to generate the layer just launching on my own machine:

```
     pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
     zip -r mypythonlibs.zip python > /dev/null
```

And then uploading the zip as a layer in aws, but I then have another error when lanching the lambda:

```
    Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems that the layer has to be built on a somehow *extended* target environment.

Comment: Why not just use `urllib`. That would not require any layers or dependencies because it is part of Pythons standard library. Even if you don't want to use `urllib`, you could use `requests`, which is probably a way better option than `curl` in your Lambda.

Comment: Thank you, @Jens, it could be a work around. Yet, only `pycurl` is able, in my understanding, to give metrics such as TTLB, TTFB and DNS lookup time for instance.

Comment: Ok. That was not clear from the code you provided. In that case `urllib` or `requests` are probably not of help.

Comment: You are right, I change the code to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours scratching my head, I managed to resolve this issue.

*TL;DR:* build the layer by using a docker image inherited from the aws one, but with the needed libraries, for instance `libcurl-devel`, `openssl-devel`, `python36-devel`. Have a look at the trick Note 3 :).

*The detailed way:*

1. Prerequisite: having Docker installed
2. In a empty directory, copy your `requirements.txt` containing `pycurl` (in my case: `pycurl~=7.43.0.5`)
3. In this same directory, create the following `Dockerfile` (cf Note 3):

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.6

RUN yum install libcurl-devel python36-devel -y

RUN yum install openssl-devel -y
ENV PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl

RUN ln -s /usr/include /var/lang/include
```

4. Build the docker image:

```
docker build -t build-python3.6-pycurl .
```

5. build the layer using this image (cf Note 2), by running:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "build-python3.6-pycurl" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/; exit"
```

6. Zip the layer by running:

```
zip mylayer.zip python > /dev/null
```

7. Send the file `mylayer.zip` to aws as a layer and make your lambda points to it (using the console, or following the tuto https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/).
8. Test your lambda and celebrate!

*Note 1.* If you want to use python 3.8, just change 3.6 or 36 by 3.8 and 38.

*Note 2.* Do not forget to remove the python folder when regenerating the layer, using admin rights if necessary.

*Note 3.* Mind the symlink in the last line of the DockerFile. Without it, `gcc` won't be able to find some header files, such as `Python.h`.

*Note 4.* Compile `pycurl` with `openssl` backend, for it is the ssl backend used in the lambda executing environment. Or else you'll get a `libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend` error when executing the lambda.